# Thread error with MKMapView and UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, mkmapview, uiimagepickercontroller

So I'm building a photo map app. I have a MKMapView and I got the camera going with UIImagePickerController, I take a picture, then return to the map. Tho when I try to pan the map after that, I get a thread error:

```
2017-05-04 16:58:11.611796+0200 Hex Pics[3569:1402345] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18ecfefe0 0x18d760538 0x18ec6aeb4 0x1006690a4 0x100668f60 0x10067a0ac 0x100073088 0x100073c10 0x18f7f3770 0x18ecadaa4 0x18ecad7a8 0x18ecad068 0x18ecaac8c 0x18ebdada4 0x190644074 0x194e95330 0x10007d0c8 0x18dbe959c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Dose anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have any arrays in your code?

Comment: I do have bunch, tho not sure witch one it's refering to.

Comment: Post some code where you're attempting to access these arrays. Basically, the code is trying to access one of these arrays beyond it's bounds.

Comment: Add exception breakpoint and it might show you where this is happening.

Comment: I don't have any arrays related to the camera and none that are updated at that point.
I tried adding breakpoints and the last line executed is:
self.imgPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Sloved it, it was one of my arrays.